# How to limit CPU usage with systemd-run

Tags: systemd, cgroups, cpulimit, systemd-run

I have a buggy program which uses 100% CPU even when it's idle.  Since fixing it isn't practical at the moment, I'd like to just limit it to be able to use no more than 10% CPU.  However no matter what I do, the process always chews up 100% of one CPU.

I found instructions on the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cgroups) that tell me to create a file containing this:

```
# cpulimit.slice
[Slice]
CPUQuota=10%
```

Apparently I can then launch a shell using these limits, like this:

```
systemd-run --slice=cpulimit.slice --uid=myuser --shell
```

This seems to work and after entering in my sudo password I get a shell, so I run a simple test that will use 100% CPU and I can stop with Ctrl+C:

```
while true; do true; done
```

I expect this to use no more than 10% CPU since it's running inside the slice, however it always uses 100% CPU!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just discovered the problem.  The `.slice` file must be placed in `/etc/systemd/system/` and you have to run `systemctl daemon-reload` first.  Then it all works.

Unfortunately the `systemd-run` command doesn't give you any error messages if you use an invalid `--slice` parameter, it just creates a new slice with no additional restrictions, called whatever name you supplied.